# Is there a windows concurrency_queue.h equivalent on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

Well I am tryng to have a queue which is concurrent, but [concurrency_queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee355358.aspx) isn't standard C++ and it's for windows, linux doesn't have it. Is there anything for linux like this (with the same functions like in the windows equivalent?)?

Edit:
This is needed to port this windows code to linux:

```
#include <concurrent_queue.h>

#ifdef defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__)
    #define SLEEP(x) { Sleep(x); }
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <process.h>
    #define OS_WINDOWS
    #define EXIT_THREAD() { _endthread(); }
    #define START_THREAD(a, b) { _beginthread( a, 0, (void *)( b ) ); }
#else
    #include <pthread.h>
    #define sscanf_s sscanf
    #define sprintf_s sprintf
    #define EXIT_THREAD() { pthread_exit( NULL ); }
    #define START_THREAD(a, b) {    pthread_t thread;\
                                pthread_create( &thread, NULL, a, (void *)( b ) ); }
#endif

using namespace std;
using namespace Concurrency;

struct QuedData
{
    int start;
    int end;
    int extraid;
    AMX * script;
    QuedData(){start = 0;end = 0;extraid = 0;script = NULL;}
    QuedData(int start_,int end_,int extraid_, AMX * script_){start = start_;end = end_;extraid = extraid_;script = script_;}
};

struct PassData //thanks to DeadMG for improvements.
{
    std::vector<cell> Paths;
    int extraid;
    AMX * script;
    cell MoveCost;
    PassData(){extraid = 0;script = NULL;MoveCost = 0;Paths.clear();}
    template<typename Iterator> PassData(Iterator begin, Iterator end, int extraid_, cell MoveCost_, AMX * script_)
        : Paths(begin, end)
    {extraid = extraid_;MoveCost = MoveCost_;script = script_;}
    ~PassData(){Paths.clear();}
};

concurrent_queue            <QuedData>          QueueVector;
concurrent_queue            <PassData>          PassVector;
PassData LocalPass;

void PLUGIN_CALL
    ProcessTick()
{
    if(PassVector.try_pop(LocalPass))
    {
        amx_Push(LocalPass.script, LocalPass.MoveCost);
        //blabla
    }
}

static cell AMX_NATIVE_CALL n_CalculatePath( AMX* amx, cell* params )
{
    QueueVector.push(QuedData(params[1],params[2],params[3],amx));
    return 1;
}

bool PLUGIN_CALL Load( void **ppData )
{
    START_THREAD( Thread::BackgroundCalculator, 0);
    return true;
}

QuedData RecievedData;
vector <cell>tbcway;
cell tbccostx;
#ifdef OS_WINDOWS
    void Thread::BackgroundCalculator( void *unused )
#else
    void *Thread::BackgroundCalculator( void *unused )
#endif
{
    while( true ){
        if(QueueVector.try_pop(RecievedData)){
            dgraph->findPath_r(xNode[RecievedData.start].NodeID ,xNode[RecievedData.end].NodeID,tbcway,tbccostx);
            PassVector.push(PassData(tbcway.begin(),tbcway.end(),RecievedData.extraid,tbccostx,RecievedData.script));
        }
        SLEEP(5);
    }
    EXIT_THREAD();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Visual C++ concurrent_queue is actually based on the Intel Threading Building Block Library
(If you open concurrent_queue.h header file in VC++ you will see an acknowledgement)

You can get the library from

http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/

The library will run on Linux as well.

Comment: which headers are specific to the queue in TBB? #include "tbb/concurrent_queue.h" I suppose? :)

Answer (score 3):

I think [threadpool](http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/) does this or an unofficial Boost enhancement called [lockfree](https://www.ohloh.net/p/lockfree) and should by now be part of `Boost::Atomics`. I haven't use both but let us know if you have any luck.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at https://github.com/romanek-adam/boost_locking_queue for the code and the article that goes with it at [Implementing a Thread-Safe Queue using Condition Variables](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html)